# how to put a timer on a button so that my melody will play after the timer ends?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need my res / raw melody to play after the timer finished( in code "Finished")
But so that I do not add the last function, nothing helps. The timer works, the melody too, but only separately, so mb can someone give me advice?

````
    lateinit var bindingClass : ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var pendingIntent: PendingIntent
    lateinit var mediaPlayer : MediaPlayer
    var counter = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        bindingClass = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(bindingClass.root)

        bindingClass.imageButton.setOnClickListener {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.raw)
             mediaPlayer.start()
        }
         bindingClass.pauseButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying)
                mediaPlayer.stop()
        }
    }
    fun playSound(view: View) {}
    fun pauseSound(view: View) {}

    fun startTimeCounter(view: View) {
        val countTime: TextView = findViewById(R.id.countTime)
        object : CountDownTimer(5000, 100) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                countTime.text = counter.toString()
                counter++

            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                countTime.text = "Finished"
            }
        } .start()

    }
}```
````

Comment: Your counter's `onFinish()` function doesn't look like it's making any attempt to play audio.  By the way, don't use `lateinit` for properties that you aren't immediately assigning in `onCreate()`. Like in this case, pressing the `pauseButton` before the `playButton` will make it crash because the property is unitialized.

Comment: hmm, about lateinit, all buttons works fine, no any crash. And about onFinish() if i add something under my function onFinish() for example: "override fun onFinish() {
                countTime.text = "Finished"    mediaPlayer.start() " its not working, so question was "what i need to add" I really confused. But anyway thank you!

Comment: You also need to create the MediaPlayer to be able to use it. What you're describing doesn't fit exactly with the code posted.

Comment: Another problem is that you're creating the MediaPlayer on the UI main thread. This can lead to UI freezes and stuttering.

Comment: YEAHU, now it works. Thank you very much again, second u alrd save me!